# Creating Modern Page with specific layout

Tags: page-layout, modern-experience, modern-pages

We actually looking for option for user to select a template before creating a modern page.

For example, in classic Publishing pages, we could create page layout templates that included default web parts and layouts.  This would allow users to quickly scaffold content while also filling in some metadata about the page itself.

Comment: Microsoft is in the process of adding page layouts for modern site pages. I believe that functionality should be rolling out very soon.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds a lot like site design for modern SharePoint ( https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-overview).
Perhaps combined with pnp templates, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpprovisioningtemplate?view=sharepoint-ps